# Conditionally calling a function in another script and using it's variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two scripts, one calling the other in Python 27. The first script, Script1.py, contains some conditional statements. Then I have a second script, Script2.py that calls the first script and passes an argument to the function, func1 imported from the first script.

However I then get an error when running the second script that the variables in func1 are not defined. Why is this? What should I do to resolve?

Thanks

Script1.py:

```
def func1(var):

    if var == '1':

        test1 = 'a'
        test2 = 'b'
        test3 = 'c'

    if var == '2':

        test1 = 'd'
        test2 = 'e'
        test3 = 'f'
```

Script2.py:

```
from Script1 import func1

func1('1')

print test1, test2, test3

func1('2')

print test1, test2, test3


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python27/Script2.py", line 5, in <module>
    print test1, test2, test3
NameError: name 'test1' is not defined
```

Comment: `if` and a single `=` don't go together.

Comment: sorry, will amend...was a typo

Comment: That will not work because the scope of those variables are local to the function.

Comment: your function should probably `return test1, test2, test3`; and then you could call it this way: `test1, test2, test3 = func1('1')`.

Comment: i figured the variables were local to that function, but how do I call them from my second script? i know you can do 'from function import var', however the issue here is the function in script one is parameterised and I am therefore unsure how to call the variables in func1 based on this conditional input...

Comment: Here is some reading about scopes: [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) ... 
[4.2. Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Comment: This is why you should return values from a function and not use globals.  You could return a tuple, e.g.: `return  test1, test2, test3` then in the call:  `test1, test2, test3 = func1('1')`

Comment: @cdarke hi, thanks for replying. I'm confused about which scripts i should be calling your code in. Could you please explain? Thanks

Comment: Hi @gdogg371, check my answer and see if it makes sense to you!

Comment: @gdogg371:  the answers given by others should make that clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func1(var):

    if var == '1':
        test1 = 'a'
        test2 = 'b'
        test3 = 'c'

    elif var == '2':
        test1 = 'd'
        test2 = 'e'
        test3 = 'f'

    # to catch error when different argument is passed
    else:
        test1 = test2 = test3 = None

    return test1, test2, test3 # return the variables, so they can be used outside
```

and:

```
from Script1 import func1

test1, test2, test3 = func1('1')

print test1, test2, test3

test1, test2, test3 = func1('2')

print test1, test2, test3
```

Comment: this gives an error of: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python27/Script2.py", line 3, in <module>
    test1, test2, test3 = func1('1')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: sorry, there was a space too much. should be fine now.

Comment: thank you. this now works perfectly in my actual code as well as the simple scenario example given in the question. I have also learned a valuable lesson on my python journey.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your code, you can define your `func1` as follows, note that I can return the values directly, and I do not need to assign them to variables

```
def func1(var):

    if var == '1':
       return 'a', 'b', 'c'
    elif var == '2':
       return 'd', 'e', 'f'
```

Then to read those values, you read the values in a variable, and print them

```
from Script1 import func1
test1, test2, test3 = func1('1')
print test1, test2, test3
#a b c
test1, test2, test3 = func1('2')
print test1, test2, test3
#d e f
```

To go one step further, you can also assign them to a list, and print as well

```
print(func1('1'))
print(func1('2'))
#('a', 'b', 'c')
#('d', 'e', 'f')
```

Answer (score 0):

in script1.py

```
T = {'test1':'', 'test2':'', 'test3':''}

def func1(var):

    if var == '1':

        T['test1'] = 'a'
        T['test2'] = 'b'
        T['test3'] = 'c'

    if var == '2':

        T['test1'] = 'd'
        T['test2'] = 'e'
        T['test3'] = 'f'
```

in script2.py

```
from script1 import (T, func1)


func1('1')

print T['test3'], T['test2'], T['test1']

func1('2')

print T['test3'], T['test2'], T['test1']
```